# VS 2010 Express for Windows Phone doesn't display images correctly in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-7

VS 2010 Express Windows Phone, Windows 7 Professional with sufficient graphics card and driver as stated in requirements.
When I start debugging my project my image on main page is cut off in the upper right hand corner and some unreadable text is present in that area.  If I quit debugging and view my app in the emulator it looks fine.  Is this something I should be concerned about?  A bug?

[image]

Comment: No , it is indicating app running in the Debug mode.. if u run the app in without debugging mode... it wont come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg588380(v=vs.105).aspx

You don't have to worry about it, since it will be displayed only when the debugger is attached. Still, if you want to remove it, just find the following line in the App.xaml.cs and remove it:

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```